# Network issues on freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine (virtualbox) - Appears to be DNS related

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns

I've just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a virtualbox vm. I can ping IP addresses, my default gateway, etc. But I can't seem to get a response when I ping google.com.

I also can't seem to wget anything using a domain name.

I can wget from 1.1.1.1.

When I try to ping google.com, this is what I'm seeing:

```
blaine@devmachine:~$ ping google.com                                                                                                             
PING google.com(den16s03-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400f:806::200e)) 56 data bytes
From _gateway (fe80::5a19:f8ff:fef4:9205%enp0s3) icmp_seq=517 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From _gateway (fe80::5a19:f8ff:fef4:9205%enp0s3) icmp_seq=518 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
```

I have the VM set to use a "bridged adapter." This has worked for me fine in the past, but now it doesn't.

This is what I see when I try to wget google.com:

```
blaine@devmachine:~/vue-chat-app$ wget google.com
--2020-04-14 05:50:35--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 2607:f8b0:400f:800::200e, 172.217.11.238
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|2607:f8b0:400f:800::200e|:80...
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by disabling IPv6. For whatever reason it seems to be broken.

I followed the instructions [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-ipv6-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)